# Unable to send a message to client using signalr in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, firefox, signalr

startup class:

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ESimSolFinancial.Startup))]
namespace ESimSolFinancial
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration());
        }
    }
}
```

Hub Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace ESimSolFinancial.Hubs
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {

        public static void SendMessage(string msg,int nCount)
        {
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.broadcastMessage(string.Format(msg), nCount);
        }
    }
}
```

in a js file i have this function:

```
function InitializeProgressBar() {
    ProgressBarShow();
    var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub;

    progressNotifier.client.broadcastMessage = function (message, count) {
        UpdateProgressBar(message, count);
    };
    $.connection.hub.url = "/signalr";
    $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling'] }).done(function () {
        //progressNotifier.client.broadcastMessage('Opening Connection',0);
    });
}
```

it is called on a click event

the click event invokes an action result in which i have this code:

```
Thread.Sleep(5000);
ProgressHub.SendMessage("Getting Ledger Data", 10);
```

to update a progressbar after long processes finish.

the messages are sent correctly in chrome and IE but firefox does not receive these messages accordingly. `UpdateProgressBar(message, count);` does not get invoked. it works sometimes when i open firebug and stop execution for a long time.

i thought it was because the long processes were not long enough, so i increased the sleep time but that was not the case.

i don't understand what i'm doing wrong here. any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
the actionresult is of the page where click event is. it seems to work only after the application has just started. after that firefox refuses to receive those messages.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors in the Firefox console when the click event is called ?

Comment: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:2309/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=mOqZQ0uzyM8ih51WabnKjKDBbl3B585Tiij5FpIGE7GnvSOSe7CMd0sKLSAP6Zf7waRYBIH8%2BgsKuqDumuSIhMhLx3C7%2Br5C7sLoBlzq2d%2BO1K0tVr6JKOTuLVK3LRyG&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22progresshub%22%7D%5D&tid=4.


it shows a second time with a very long connection token. what does this mean?

Comment: This error message can be seen in Firebug if negotiation of the WebSocket transport fails and another transport is used instead. This behavior is by design.

Comment: is transport without WebSocket possible? if not than, how can i properly use this? forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called server function for click event in js

```
 progressNotifier.server.SendMessage(msg,count);
```

You can modify client code ... by calling server function

```
  function InitializeProgressBar() {
     ProgressBarShow();
    var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub;

     progressNotifier.client.broadcastMessage = function (message, count) {
       UpdateProgressBar(message, count);
     };
     $.connection.hub.url = "/signalr";
     $.connection.hub.start({ transport: ['webSockets', 'longPolling']   
        }).done(function () {

     //Call to server function(SendMessage) made .This fuction broadcasts to all clients 
    //by calling client side(broadcast message ) function of all users
    progressNotifier.server.SendMessage(msg,count);

      //progressNotifier.client.broadcastMessage('Opening Connection',0);
    });
 }
```

Please try this.I cant run the program in an application. But this is how signal R works.One client calls a server function on an event(or server replies on no call but some logic) and the server broadcasts realtime notifications to selected groups,or selected users or all of them(in client side).

```
 $('#id').click(function(){
   progressNotifier.server.SendMessage(msg,count); 
  });
```

> Server function has to be called

Comment: `InitializeProgressBar()` this function is called from the click event

Comment: try calling the server function SendMessage() from InitializeProgressBar().One client has to call server function, only then can the server give realtime notification to all clients.